# Flask-SQLAlchemy many-to-many adjacency list changes after commit

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, adjacency-list

I have a model that has a many-to-many relationship with itself: An operation can be prevented by another operation or itself.

```
operation_to_operation_association_table = db.Table(
    "preventing_operations",
    db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True),
    db.Column("preventing_operation_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("operation.id")),
    db.Column("prevents_operation_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("operation.id")))



class Operation(BaseModel): # BaseModel defines id and creation/update times
    name = db.Column(db.String)

    bodypart_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(BodyPart.id))
    bodypart = db.relationship("BodyPart", backref="operations")

    prevents = db.relationship("Operation", secondary=operation_to_operation_association_table,
                               foreign_keys=[operation_to_operation_association_table.c.preventing_operation_id],
                               backref="prevented_by")


    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other and self.name == other.name and self.bodypart == other.bodypart
```

Then in the shell, from a fresh database:

```
In [1]: bp = BodyPart(name="liver")

In [2]: db.session.add(bp)

In [3]: db.session.commit()

In [4]: o1, o2 = Operation(name="viewing", bodypart=bp), Operation(name="removing", bodypart=bp)

In [5]: db.session.add_all([o1, o2])

In [6]: db.session.commit()

In [7]: o1, o2
Out[7]: (Viewing the liver (1), Removing the liver (2))

In [8]: o1.prevents, o2.prevents
Out[8]: ([], [])

In [9]: o2.prevents.append(o1)

In [10]: o1.prevents, o2.prevents
Out[10]: ([], [Viewing the liver (1)])

In [11]: db.session.commit()

In [12]: o1.prevents, o2.prevents
Out[12]: ([Viewing the liver (1)], [])
```

Committing switches the lists around?!

Logging queries, the insert-query SQLAlchemy sends the database seems to be wrong:

```
INSERT INTO preventing_operations (prevents_operation_id) VALUES (?)
with values (1,)
```

When it should be:

```
INSERT INTO preventing_operations (prevents_operation_id, preventing_operation_id) VALUES (?)
with values (2, 1)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I defining my relationship incorrectly? Then why does it only change when I commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with `foreign_keys` setup and I am actually not sure what exactly need to be done to foreign_keys.

But I suggest to use `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin` instead. This way the setup is more obvious for me (and it works):

```
prevents = relationship(
    "Operation",
    secondary=operation_to_operation,
    primaryjoin=id == operation_to_operation.c.preventing_operation_id,
    secondaryjoin=id == operation_to_operation.c.prevents_operation_id,
    backref="prevented_by")
```

Here is [the working example](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/sql-alchemy/many_many_save_issue.py) and [module with base model](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/sql-alchemy/base.py).

Run the example as this:
- download both files, save into the same folder (or clone the repo)
- run `python many_many_save_issue.py.

I tested it with SQLAlchemy==1.0.6.

Comment: Using that gives back `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not locate any simple equality expressions involving locally mapped foreign key columns for primary join condition 'preventing_operations.preventing_operation_id = :preventing_operation_id_1' on relationship Operation.prevents.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated in the join condition with the foreign() annotation. To allow comparison operators other than '==', the relationship can be marked as viewonly=True.`

Comment: @thepandaatemyface I actually tested it before positing, here is the [working example](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/sql-alchemy/many_many_save_issue.py) and you'll also need [this file](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/sql-alchemy/base.py) to run it. Just download both, save near and run `python many_many_save_issue.py`. I was able to reproduce and then fix your issue.

Comment: I tested it with SQLAlchemy==1.0.6

Comment: @thepandaatemyface I am glad it helped ))